# SymmetircDS: Extract Frequency by Channel

Tags: symmetricds

I'm trying to limit the extract frequency and found two ways in user guide (https://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.9/html/user-guide.html#_extract_frequency_by_channel). None of them are working.

1) By setting `extract_period_millis`.

```
update sym_channel set extract_period_millis = 30000, last_update_time=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where channel_id='channel_bps2swd'
```

After that, I was receiving the following error message on console:

```
[server] - SymmetricServlet - Error while processing GET request for node: 0001 at 127.0.0.1 with path: /server/pull
    org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Failed to execute sql: null
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.translate(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:302)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlReadCursor.<init>(JdbcSqlReadCursor.java:120)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.queryForCursor(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:140)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.query(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:199)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.query(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:195)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.query(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:185)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.AbstractSqlTemplate.query(AbstractSqlTemplate.java:121)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.ConfigurationService.getNodeChannels(ConfigurationService.java:436)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.ConfigurationService.getSuspendIgnoreChannelLists(ConfigurationService.java:531)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.PullUriHandler.handlePull(PullUriHandler.java:112)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.PullUriHandler.handleWithCompression(PullUriHandler.java:100)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.AbstractCompressionUriHandler.handle(AbstractCompressionUriHandler.java:84)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.SymmetricServlet.service(SymmetricServlet.java:114)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:833)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
            at org.jumpmind.symmetric.web.HttpMethodFilter.doFilter(HttpMethodFilter.java:62)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:243)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter arg '0001' type: -2147483648 caused exception: Invalid parameter index 1.
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.setValues(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:1027)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlReadCursor.<init>(JdbcSqlReadCursor.java:92)
            ... 44 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid parameter index 1.
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.getParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:543)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setParameter(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:612)
            at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setString(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:892)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135)
            at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:453)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:241)
            at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:172)
            at org.jumpmind.db.sql.JdbcSqlTemplate.setValues(JdbcSqlTemplate.java:1023)
            ... 45 more
    [server] - NodeConcurrencyInterceptor - Error building response headers
```

I had to set back `extract_period_millis = 0` to solve this error message.

Note: Table `SYM_NODE_CHANNEL_CTL` is empty

2) By setting start/endtime to on table `SYM_NODE_GROUP_CHANNEL_WND` for associated channel.

It didn't have any effects. Changes were synced shortly after they have occured.

System:
Symmetric 3.9.12, Windows 10 x64, mssql

Any solutions to set the sync frequency?

Answer (score 1):

If your just looking to change the sync frequency you could use the following parameters as they are both defaulted to 1 min (60000ms).

job.pull.period.time.ms

job.push.period.time.ms

Answer (score 0):

In class 
org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.ConfigurationServiceSqlMap.java

add this 
**putSql("selectNodeChannelControlLastExtractTimeSql" ,"select channel_id,last_extract_time from sym_node_channel_ctl where node_id=?");**